# How does the following line of code Simplify to ....?

Tags: linear-algebra

How does

[image]

Simplify to

[image]

I don't get the middle part... [image]

Please give me a explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a technique that I call "introducing special zero value".

This is a useful technique in some factoring cases, for example in proving the identity $a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$. We introduce a special zero value using the term $ab$.

> Example:
>
> $$a^2-b^2=a^2-ab+ab-b^2=a(a-b)+b(a-b)=(a+b)(a-b)$$

Similarly, in the example you posed in your question,

$$p_in\cdot p-p_in\cdot p=0$$

and as such, you added a net zero value which doesn't affect the original expression. I believe it was done so that the expression can be factored/simplified.